# ujson Package Installation Error in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.6, ujson

When I try to install `ujson` package in python 3.6 on Windows 10, (which is needed for binance-python library installation) I got this error:

```
C:\Users\MHT\python_projects\crypto\env\Scripts
(env) λ pip install ujson
Collecting ujson
  Using cached ujson-4.0.2.tar.gz (7.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: ujson
  Building wheel for ujson (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mht\python_projects\crypto\env\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\mht\python_projects\crypto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\MHT\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfwaht9wj'
       cwd: C:\Users\MHT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-97ynb6ua\ujson_0cc2905684bb497985ff0e4ac258eafe
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'ujson' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\deps
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\deps\double-conversion
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\deps\double-conversion\double-conversion
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\lib
  creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\python
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I./python -I./lib -I./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion -Ic:\users\mht\python_projects\crypto\env\include -Ic:\users\mht\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include -Ic:\users\mht\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include" /EHsc /Tp./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.cc /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.obj -D_GNU_SOURCE
  bignum-dtoa.cc
  ./deps/double-conversion/double-conversion\bignum-dtoa.cc(28): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'math.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ujson
Failed to build ujson
ERROR: Could not build wheels for ujson which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: math.h is a fundamental header file if i remember correctly, so you likely need to install a C/C++ development toolchain of some kind. i don't know off the top of my head exactly what toolchain you need though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install Visual Studio, here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/. Often, packages depend on Visual Studio for C/C++ compilers.

It appears it terminates because running the below command:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

failed. Installing Visual Studio should fix this.

Comment: i installed visual studio c++ v14+ build tools befor, but i can not help me

Comment: it is Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: thank u, i reinstall visual studio c++ v14+ again using MVSC build tools and it solve my issue.